# Continuous surjective function

Tags: real-analysis

I saw this question earlier,

"Does there exists a continuous surjective function $f$ such that $f:(0,1) \to [0, 1)$? Discuss if $f:[0,1) \to (0,1)$."

I don't really know how should I approach this type of question, what kind of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first case, consider a parabola symmetric about the line $x=\frac12$. See if you can massage it so that the domain is $(0,1)$ and the range is $[0,1)$.

The second case is more complicated, but still doable. Start with $f(0)=\frac12$ (so that $0$ is in the domain). Then you need to oscillate between the lines $y=\frac12 x-\frac12$ and $y=\frac12 x+\frac12$, with an ever-increasing frequency as you approach $x=1$. See if you can construct an explicit function based on a sine wave.

Comment: Ah I was expecting that I had to come up with a rigorous proof of some sort of the existence of these functions but I guess this solves the problem, thanks! However, can we discuss the existence from continuity standpoint rather than finding one explicitly?

Comment: @JustWandering: Why?!

Comment: haha not any particular reasons but since this was from an Analysis exam I thought that is the intended route to be taken

Comment: @JustWandering: no, I don't think so. It is perfectly normal and acceptable to prove the existence of an object by giving an example of it. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right, I guess I have to prove it's continuous to be complete, which isn't really that hard

Comment: @JustWandering: I doubt that you even have to do that, in these two cases. You are over-thinking this!

Comment: do there exist two intervals such that it doesn't exists a continuous surjective function from one interval to another? Just kinda curious!

Comment: @JustWandering: [This link](https://planetmath.org/bijectionbetweenclosedandopeninterval) states that there is no continuous surjective function from $[0,1]$ to $(0,1)$.